# Removing the integers in the output when inputted with a String

Tags: java, string

I am struggling on my code. My prof told us to make a line of code in Eclipse which, when a string like a "q1w2e3r4t5y" is input, will output only "qwerty". The numbers are removed. This can be easily achieved using a regular expression. My problem is, it is my first year in coding and I'm not yet familiar with the code using Java.

The code using regex is

```
String inputString = "q1w2e3r4t5y";

System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll("\\d",""));
```

And the console/output is

```
qwerty
```

Please tell me what code is the best way to execute this output without using the regex.

Comment: One single line of code? There is `Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))` one could use in a for loop, or stream: `inputString.chars().filter(c -> !Character.isDigit((char)c)).forEach(System.out.print((char)c));`. But that is a questionable "short" solution.

Comment: There are several ways and what is best depends on the context. Your professor probably did not want you to find the best way but to apply what you have learned already, to solve the problem. If you are in the first year, you probably learned something about loops. Go through the string char by char in a loop and check if you hit a digit or a letter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "q1w2e3r4t5y";
        String newS ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            String s = inputString.charAt(i)+"";
            try { 
                Integer.parseInt(s);            
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO: build the string here
                newS+=s;              
            }       
           
        }

        System.out.println(newS);//qwerty

    
      }
}
```